# Pytest and Dynamic fixture modules

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing functional tests using pytest for a software that can run locally and in the cloud. I want to create 2 modules, each with the same module/fixture names, and have pytest load one or the other depending if I'm running tests locally or in the cloud:

```
/fixtures
/fixtures/__init__.py
/fixtures/local_hybrids
/fixtures/local_hybrids/__init__.py
/fixtures/local_hybrids/foo.py
/fixtures/cloud_hybrids
/fixtures/cloud_hybrids/__init__.py
/fixtures/cloud_hybrids/foo.py
/test_hybrids/test_hybrids.py
```

`foo.py` (both of them):

```
import pytest
@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    return True
```

`/fixtures/__init__.py`:

```
if True:
    import local_hybrids as hybrids
else:
    import cloud_hybrids as hybrids
```

`/test_hybrids/test_hybrids.py`:

```
from fixtures.hybrids.foo import my_fixture

def test_hybrid(my_fixture):
   assert my_fixture
```

The last code block doesn't work of course, because `import fixtures.hybrids` is looking at the file system instead of `__init__.py`'s "fake" namespace, which isn't like `from fixtures import hybrids`, which works (but then you cannot use the fixtures as the names would involve dot notation).

I realize that I could play with pytest_generate_test to alter the fixture dynamically (maybe?) but I'd really hate managing each fixture manually from within that function... I was hoping the dynamic import (if x, import this, else import that) was standard Python, unfortunately it clashes with the fixtures mechanism:

```
import fixtures
def test(fixtures.hybrids.my_fixture):  # of course it doesn't work :)
    ...
```

I could also import each fixture function one after the other in init; more legwork, but still a viable option to fool pytest and get fixture names without dots.

Show me the black magic. :) Can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it's better to define a fixture - `environment` or other nice name.

This fixture can be just a getter from os.environ['KEY'] or you can add custom command line argument like [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-services/blob/master/pytest_services/plugin.py) 
then use it like [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-services/blob/master/pytest_services/service.py#L17)
and the final use is [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-services/blob/master/pytest_services/mysql.py#L17).

What im trying to tell is that you need to switch thinking into dependency injection: everything should be a fixture. In your case (and in my plugin as well), runtime environment should be a fixture, which is checked in all other fixtures which depend on the environment.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this possibility (that's how I was doing it originally) but I really want to avoid even importing the cloud modules if I am running local tests, and vice-versa. Because of this, importing each symbol one after the other (the 'more legwork' suggestion in my original post) is more optimal to me. Thanks for taking the time to answer though ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing something here: If you want to re-use those fixtures you need to say it explicitly:

```
from fixtures.hybrids.foo import my_fixture

@pytest.mark.usefixtures('my_fixture')
def test_hybrid(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture
```

In that case you could tweak pytest as following:

```
from local_hybrids import local_hybrids_fixture
from cloud_hybrids import cloud_hybrids_fixture

fixtures_to_test = {
    "local":None,
    "cloud":None
}

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("local_hybrids_fixture")
def test_add_local_fixture(local_hybrids_fixture):
    fixtures_to_test["local"] = local_hybrids_fixture

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("cloud_hybrids_fixture")
def test_add_local_fixture(cloud_hybrids_fixture):
    fixtures_to_test["cloud"] = cloud_hybrids_fixture

def test_on_fixtures():
    if cloud_enabled:
        fixture = fixtures_to_test["cloud"]
    else:
        fixture = fixtures_to_test["local"]
    ...
```

If there are better solutions around I am also interested ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there is a "good way" of doing that in python, but still it is possible with a little amount of hacking. You can update sys.path for the subfolder with fixtures you would like to use and import fixtures directly. In dirty case it look's like that:

for your fixtures/__init__.py:

```
if True:
    import local as hybrids
else:
    import cloud as hybrids

def update_path(module):
    from sys import path
    from os.path import join, pardir, abspath
    mod_dir = abspath(join(module.__file__, pardir))
    path.insert(0, mod_dir)

update_path(hybrids)
```

and in the client code (test_hybrids/test_hybrids.py) :

```
import fixtures
from foo import spam

spam()
```

In other cases you can use much more complex actions to perform a fake-move of all modules/packages/functions etc from your cloud/local folder directly into the fixture's __init__.py. Still, I think - it does not worth a try.

One more thing - black magic is not the best thing to use, I would recommend you to use a dotted notation with "import X from Y" - this is much more stable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the pytest plugins feature and put your fixtures in separate modules. Then at runtime select which plug-in you’ll be drawing from via a command line argument or an environment variable. It needs to be something global because you need to place different `pytest_plugins` list assignments based on the global value.

Take a look at the section Conditional Plugins from this repo https://github.com/jxramos/pytest_behavior/tree/main/conditional_plugins